Samsung phone won't charge from laptop
I recently switched from iOS to Android (iPhone 13 Pro to Samsung Galaxy S23 to be exact)
On the occasion I use my laptop to charge my phone through its USB-C port. It's a Lenovo Yoga 6, and with my iPhone it usually stays charging even while the laptop is closed.
However, my Android doesn't do that. Once the laptop closes it stops charging after about a minute. It still tells me it's "USB Charging" on the Notification Panel, but the charging icon isn't there, and the level still goes down. It charges fine everywhere else. I can't tell whether this is an issue with my phone or laptop, as my laptop was charging the iPhone just fine meanwhile my Android reacts just fine when plugged anywhere else. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

iPhone 13 requires less power to charge than your Android device. Are you plugging in the device into a PD port?
